# How can I solve for X in a sum function?

Tags: statistics, summation

I have this inequality constrain, let's call it **(*)**

$$\frac{1}{C}\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}Y_{i} < Z$$

(forgive me if it should be $i=0$ and $n-1$, this is my first question here and I'm very rusty)

Can I find out the expected value of X?

e.g. if X's mean is this (again forgive me if I have a silly mistake, it has been a while):

$\bar{X} = \frac{\sum X_{i}}{n}$

**Can I solve (*) for $\bar{X}$?**

Comment: Not really, no... especially if you don't know anything about the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Thanks! @MichaelChirico What if I have the values for $Y_{0}$ to $Y_{n}$? is there a way to solve it then?

Comment: Nothing exciting. In that case, basically you have a weighted average of your $X_i$. As far as I know there's no easy relationship between an object's weighted average and its uniform average.

Comment: Unless of course $\mathbb{V}[Y]$=0, i.e. $Y_i\equiv y$

Comment: Consider a simple case, with $n=2$, where you can draw all the relationships imposed in the $(X_1,X_2)$ plane.